# MYSQL Updating single matching row instead of all

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, min

I am working with mysql and hit a wall. Please see my db-fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nhY88U8gtunUqRaSBLBTrT/0

item_storage is a static table. It is created once and then just updated occasionally.

operation is a dynamic table that gets created when an operation is started and then cleared once the operation is finished.

Every row in operation has unique ID value. For example, in the operation table , I have just 2 rows, both have unique serial numbers. I need to update my item_storage table according to the operation table.

Since in my operation table I have 1 item with serial "AAAAAA" and 1 item with "BBBBBB", I must update my item_storage and set the current_operation and ID to be the same as in the operation table.

The issue is, inside my item_storage, I can have multiple items with matching serial numbers. The only difference they have, is different Slave ID. I want to randomly choose (Or select the one with lower Slave ID ) and update only one matching serial item instead of updating all of them.

As you can see in my sql fiddle , both of the items with Serial "AAAAAA" gets updated in my item_storage table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query:

```
SELECT Serial, MIN(Slave_ID) Slave_ID 
FROM item_storage  
GROUP BY Serial
```

you get the min `Slave_ID` for each `Serial` in `item_storage`.

Join `item_storage` to the above query and also to `operation`:

```
UPDATE item_storage i
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Serial, MIN(Slave_ID) Slave_ID 
  FROM item_storage  
  GROUP BY Serial
) s ON s.Slave_ID = i.Slave_ID 
INNER JOIN operation o ON o.Serial = i.Serial
SET i.Current_operation = o.Quantity, 
    i.ID = o.ID 
WHERE o.Statusv <> 'DONE';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=053e80f96d45af4b09be39943ca29aed).

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need. I have managed to execute this query and it works. Could you please explain how this query works? I am not really understanding how INNER JOIN works

Comment: @TheBestPlayer you have to study about joins as it is a basic operation in sql. A good source is here: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/ Also, check how the tables in your question are joined with a SELECT statement: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54be20637a0c531ed189d5b9be273193

Comment: Thanks for the links. It is still not fully clear to me regarding this nested INNER JOIN. Especially this part is the most confusing for me ```s ON s.Slave_ID = i.Slave_ID ```. First of all, I am not fully understanding what is "s" and why do you compare ID's of the same table? Is this required to find the lowest value one?

Comment: @TheBestPlayer by joining the subquery to the table `item_storage`, only the rows with the min Slave_ID are returned and finally updated. `s` is the alias of the subquery and is used as a prefix to qualify its columns.

Comment: Hello again @forpas. I have been using the query and now just come across an issue. If I have only one "AAAAAA" serial number in my operation, it will select the lower ID one from the item_storage table and that works as expected. However, there are cases where my operation table has multiple instances of "AAAAAA". In that case, I need to select from the item_storage table. Please see example here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nhY88U8gtunUqRaSBLBTrT/2. Could you help me modify the query accordingly to get that to work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @TheBestPlayer I don't understand that: "I need to select from the item_storage table". The code works and updates in `item_storage` the rows that have the lower Slave ID.

Comment: Yes that works as expected. I only want to select the lower slave ID when there are multiple values to select from. For example when I have only 1 "AAAAAA" in operation table but I have multiple choices in item_storage, then it must select the lower slave ID one ). However, when in operation table I have 2 instances of "AAAAAA", and I have atleast 2 available instances of 'AAAAAA' in item_storage table, it must select both in random order ( dont know which one is more convenient) It does not matter for me which ID's they are assigned unless they are unique for both instances. Hope its clear

Comment: @TheBestPlayer this is a different requirement for which you must ask a new question.